# Changing Twitter and Facebook share images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter, metadata

## Where I'm at

- I have a series of 30 slides and as you scroll down the page an anchor
  gets appended to the url (eg. #day1, #day2, #day3 ... #day30)
- I'm looking for a way to change the `meta name="twitter:image` and
  `meta property="og:image"` so when the user is on `slide/#day3` and the link
  gets clicked, the url is for corresponding day's image `day3.jpg`
- I will be pulling the data for each of these slides from `data.js` which is in JSON format

### scripts.js

```
$('.twitter-slide').click(function() {
    $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', 'linkToPicture');
});
```

### data.js

```
var data = [
 {
   "Day": 1,
   "Slide": "#day1",
   "Description": "Hungry by early afternoon. Thinking about all foods as either forbidden or compliant constantly.",
   "Extra": "",
   "Tweet": "Hungry by early afternoon.",
   "Background": "#ffffd9",
   "Font": "#111",
   "Image": ""
 },
 {
   "Day": 2,
   "Slide": "#day2",
   "Description": "Ate a whole avocado and truckful of nuts as late afternoon snack. Still feeling low key hungry.",
   "Extra": "",
   "Tweet": "Ate a whole avocado and truckful of nuts as late afternoon snack.",
   "Background": "#ffffd9",
   "Font": "#111",
   "Image": ""
 },
 {
   "Day": 3,
   "Slide": "#day3",
   "Description": "Have three water-based beverages at my desk: Ice water, hot water and water with lemon.",
   "Extra": "",
   "Tweet": "Have three water-based beverages at my desk: Ice water, hot water and water with lemon.",
   "Background": "#ffffd9",
   "Font": "#111",
   "Image": ""
 }
]
```